# How to properly scope a lock

Tags: java, scope, reentrantlock

Let's say I have a `ReentrantLock`,

```
ReentrantLock foo = new ReentrantLock();
```

and a method `bar` that uses the lock,

```
public void bar()
{
    foo.lock();

    try
    {
        methodOne();
    }
    finally
    {
        foo.unlock();
    }
}
```

and `methodOne` calls a method `methodTwo` that also uses the lock,

```
public void methodTwo()
{
    foo.lock();

    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    finally
    {
        foo.unlock();
    }
}
```

is it better to release the lock in `bar` before I call `methodOne`? In general, is it good practice to release the lock before calling another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not do that. If you do it, any concurrent thread could acquire the lock in the middle of the `bar()` method, which is precisely what you want to avoid by using a lock.

It's called ReentrantLock precisely because it allows acquiring the lock multiple times in the same thread. A counter is incremented each time `lock()` is called, and decremented each time `unlock()` is called, so you just need to make sure `unlock()` is always called in a finally block.

Note that the code would be less fragile by simply using synchronized blocks, because it's impossible to forget closing a synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

Release the lock when the critical operations the lock "protects" are done.  No sooner.